# Need help with hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) Cakephp find

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to query a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship in Cakephp 1.3, but it looks like the SQL query being run is not doing a Join on the many to many table.

I have a users table, projects table, and users_projects table. I want to get a list of all projects a user is associated with in a separate Allocations controller.

I have been reading the cakephp book on the topic: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

So I have been trying this:

```
var_dump($this->Allocation->User->Project->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('Project.user_id'=>'21'))));
```

However that does not work, It returns nothing and this error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Projects.user_id' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 681]

Query: SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name` FROM `projects` AS `Project` WHERE `Projects`.`user_id` = '21'
```

It looks like cakephp is not doing the required join.

This is in my projects model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'users_projects',
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
```

And this is in my users model:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'className' => 'Project',
        'joinTable' => 'users_projects',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'project_id',
        'unique' => true,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
```

So, what is the correct syntax to get the list of projects for a given user on a many to many relationship in cakephp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using the find type '[list](http://book.cakephp.org/view/810/find-list)'. Cake's default behaviour is to select the ID and NAME fields when using this find type.

Change your find type to 'all' to retrieve the results you are expecting:

`var_dump($this->Allocation->User->Project->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('Project.user_id'=>'21'))));`

Comment: When changing to all I still get the same error. Here is the SQL output: Query: SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`description`, `Project`.`created`, `Project`.`modified` FROM `projects` AS `Project`   WHERE `Projects`.`user_id` = '21'

Comment: I also want the returned data be be in a list format to use in a html form.

Comment: Have you also changed the 'joinTable' => 'users_projects' after renaming your join table in both the User and Project models?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps that's because you didn't make the two table names connected in alphabetical order.`users_projects` should be `projects_users`.

Comment: @mrlanrat,but what do you want your query result look like?

Comment: I want just the Projects and IDs of the projects associated with the given user.

Comment: @mrlanrat,you already did that since you've specified `Project.user_id`.

Comment: I lost 4 hours , just that a name of my table of hasandbelongstomany was inversed .... GOD SAVE AS